# How to scale homogenously and completely a lattice xyplot in R?

Tags: r, lattice

I need to produce a lattice xyplot and fit it in a 8 cm x 8 cm pdf document.

I already made this plot. It is perfectly proportional on a 7 in x 7 in graph. I have been trying to scale it proportionally to a 8 cm x 8 cm graph, but with little success: the command "scales" works only on axis font label (but not on ticks length for instance), a standard "cex" in the xyplot works only on symbol size. I'd like to scale proportionally the whole plot (distance of labels from axis, tick lengths, legend etc...).

Thanks!

Here is a possible code:

```
# libraries
library(lattice)
library(grid)
library(RColorBrewer)

#creating dataset
x <- rnorm(100,10,3)
y <- rnorm(100,3,10)
z <- seq(1,100)

data <- data.frame(x,y)
data$z <- z
data$col <- heat.colors(100)

#making well scaled plot
pdf("plot.pdf")

my.legend <- packGrob(
    draw.colorkey(key=list(col = heat.colors,at = do.breaks(range(data$z,na.rm=T),100))),
    textGrob(expression(paste("z (no units)")), x = -.3, y = 0.5, just = c("left", "centre")), 
    height=unit(2, "lines"),side="top", dynamic=T)

xyplot(y~x, data, aspect="fill", type=c("p","g"), pch=21, col=grey(.2), fill=data$col, xlab=list(label=expression(paste("x axis label"[bla],", ",mu,"-"))),ylab=list(label=expression(paste("y axis label"[bla],", ",mu,"-"))),
       legend=list(right=list(fun=my.legend)),
       panel=function(x,y,...){
           panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       }   
)
dev.off()

#trying to make a 8cm x 8cm plot
pdf("plot_small.pdf",width=8/2.54,height=8/2.54)

my.legend <- packGrob(
    draw.colorkey(key=list(col = heat.colors,at = do.breaks(range(data$z,na.rm=T),100))),
    textGrob(expression(paste("z (no units)")), x = -.3, y = 0.5, just = c("left", "centre")), 
    height=unit(2, "lines"),side="top", dynamic=T)

xyplot(y~x, data, aspect="fill", type=c("p","g"), pch=21, col=grey(.2), fill=data$col, cex=.5, xlab=list(label=expression(paste("x axis label"[bla],", ",mu,"-")),cex=.5),ylab=list(label=expression(paste("y axis label"[bla],", ",mu,"-")),cex=.5),
       legend=list(right=list(fun=my.legend)),
       panel=function(x,y,...){
           panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       },
       scales=list(cex=.5)
)
dev.off()
```

Comment: It's 2.54 cm/inch, not 2.56, but I suspect that is not your problem. As I understand, you want an exact, reduced replica.  I can imagine that would be tough to do within R; couldn't you just shrink the 7"x7" , with something like ImageMagick?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inch to cm! :-) 
Sure I can. But then the labels, the dots, the ticks are too small to be intelligible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nicely rescale lattice figures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026196/how-to-nicely-rescale-lattice-figures)